# How to build Android App Bundle using Xamarin Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I see that Google Play doesn't allow apk format anymore, it requires Android App Bundle.

[This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/) said:

> To enable support for Android App Bundles, you’ll need to opt-in to
> the bundle value of the Android Package Format property within your
> Android options. As you do this, ensure you change your project to a
> Release configuration as app bundles are intended for release packages
> only. To do this you can follow these steps:
>
> ```
> 1. Right click your project, and select Properties.
> 2. Navigate to Android Options.
> 3. Change your configuration to Release.
> 4. Change the Android Package Format to bundle.
> ```

[image: Android Package Format image]

But I can't find that option in my Visual Studio 2015's Android Options.
[image: VS 2015 Android Options image]

I want to stick to Visual Studio 2015 because I don't have time to upgrade (also upgrade software on the old hardware may cause lag, I may need to buy a new laptop which I really don't want).
Is there a way I can build Android App Bundle using Visual Studio 2015 (or using Tool from Google?) or I have to install Visual Studio 16.4 or higher on Windows?

Comment: VS2015 reached the end of it's support cycle in 2020.

Comment: @Jason : But is there a work around? maybe command line or something, I check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.4#initial-support-for-android-app-bundle-publishing-format  but my .csproj don't have the tag `<AndroidPackageFormat>`

Comment: I doubt it.  Xamarin hasn't supported VS2015 for quite some time, so the latest Android SDK and tools will not work with it.

Comment: Could it help you ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT - I decided to upgrade to VS2019, took me a day to upgrade but saved me a lot of headache, VS2015 is just too exhausted to develop Mobile app.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT - I don't know which solution is better, the workaround (create app bundles from AppCenter -> haven't tested so I can't verify if it works) or upgrade (upgrade is an advice to save headache, but if the hardware is too weak to upgrade or you can't have VS2019 license, then upgrade solution is unusable). So I'll leave the decision for the voters, the answer with more vote will jump on top.

Answer (score 10):

For Visual Studio 2019, go to the property of the Xamarin.Android project. Under the "Android Options" side menu, select "bundle" for the "Android Package Format".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do this in **Visual Studio 2015** ,because this feature was added in **Visual Studio 2019** `16.4`.

You could check the release-notes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.4#16.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create App Bundles from AppCenter and push the build to Playstore directly through it.

Check this blog.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundles-azure-devops/

Check this documentation if you are not familiar with the app center.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/